# Preprocessor not working in assembly code

Tags: assembly

I have a header file that defines the following:

```
#define BLA 1
```

Now I want to include this header file into my assembly code:

```
#include "myinc.h"

    .file   "main.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "ABCDEFGHIJK.\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB6:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    mov ebp, esp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    and esp, -16
    sub esp, 16
    call    ___main
    mov DWORD PTR [esp], OFFSET FLAT:LC0
    call    _puts
    mov eax, 0
    mov ebx, BLA
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE6:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.1"
    .def    _puts;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

Unfortunately, the build output is as follows:

```
as "-ID:\\Dev\\ws\\Foobar\\inc" -o "src\\main.o" "..\\src\\main.S" 
gcc -o Foobar.exe "src\\main.o" 
src\main.o:main.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `BLA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Although the header file can be resolved, I get `undefined reference to`BLA'`. If I define`BLA`directly in the`S` file, I get the same result.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: The assembler `as` doesn't run the C preprocessor for you. If you want to run the C preprocessor on assembly files, consider executing the assembler through `gcc`: `gcc -ID:\\Dev\\ws\\Foobar\\inc -o src\\main.o ..\\src\\main.S`.

Comment: Sidenote: The **C** preprocessor does not work in Python, Ada or Pacsal either. Simply because they are completely unrelated languages, like Assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The assembler `as` is a pure assembler. It's not a frontend like `gcc` (which invokes multiple programs, including the preprocessor when needed).

You either need to run the preprocessor yourself, or use the `gcc` frontend program for the assembler file too:

```
gcc -ID:/Dev/ws/Foobar/inc -c ../src/main.S
gcc -o Foobar.exe ../src/main.o
```

---

The `gcc` frontend program recognizes files with the ending `.S` (upper-case S) to be assembler files that needs preprocessing, and will run them through the preprocessor. It also recognizes files with the ending `.s` (lower-case s) as assembler files that *don't* need to be preprocessed.